# What are the maximumnorm and supremumnorm of a vector when having a basis?

Tags: normed-spaces

I have a perhaps stupid question.
When having a finite-dimensional Vectorspace $X$ (f.e. n-dimensional) and when knowing a basis $V=\left\{v_1,...,v_n\right\}$ of it, so any $x\in X$ can be written as $x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i$.

What is then the maximumnorm of x? And what is the supremumnorm?

Greetings, math12

Comment: Are you asking, whether the $\sup$-norm of $x$ is independent from the basis?

Comment: I simply do not know how it is defined. :-) But your question interests me, too, of course.

Comment: To put it another way: I do not know what the maximumnorm of a vector is, which is written as the linear combination of the basis vectors. And I have the same problem for the supremumnorm.

Comment: As far as I know, $\|x\|_\sup = \max_i\alpha_i$ and this certainly depends on the basis.

Comment: Not $\lVert x\rVert_{\mbox{sup}}=\max_i \lvert\alpha_i\rvert$?

Comment: Yes, with absolute values.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: No problem at all, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, the maximum norm of a vector $(\alpha_i)_i$ (coordinated in a fixed basis), as Ilya commented, is
$$\|x\|_{\max}= \max_i{|\alpha_i|}\ .$$

I would say, that the sup norm arises rather on *infinite* dimensional vector spaces, where, in most cases, the elements are some *functions* $X\to\Bbb R$. (If $X=\Bbb N$, we get the real *sequences*.)

For those, $\|f\|_{\sup} =\displaystyle\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$.  In $\Bbb R$, the supremum of any set exists. In case when it is guaranteed that the supremum value is taken by $f$ (i.e., $f$ has a *maximum* -- for example if $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous), then it can also be called a maximum norm, and then $\|f\|_{\max}=\|f\|_{\sup}$.

Comment: You're welcome :)